# WebSocket sending an HTTP header on connection - how to prevent?

Tags: c#, websocket

When I open a web socket to my server - it looks like the client is automatically sending an HTTP request as part of the first payload. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

That is the nature of the web socket protocol. It starts with a handshake done over simple HTTP

```
GET /mychat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com
```

More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake

You cannot create a websocket without this handshake.